# Firebase messageId

Tags: firebase, firebase-cloud-messaging

I'm sending push notifications by topic using firebase. The response I get looks like this `{ messageId: 'mymessageid'}`

I can't find anywhere I can use this ID to look up information on the notification I sent. I've been through the docs for both client and server side firebase libraries.

Is there a way to use the `messageId` returned from a send to topic to look up information about the notification's status?

Comment: What do you mean by "the notification's status"? What are you trying to find?

Comment: If I send a notification to a device group it will send back a response with successCount, failureCount, and the failedDeviceId list. I'm trying to figure out if I need to save this messageId for use later, or if it has no real use. It seems strange to return an id if there's no use for it, so my thought is that I just can't find the use.

Comment: So you're just wondering what are the use cases for this ID?

Comment: Yeah that would be a fair way to phrase it, especially since I have 0 use cases.

Comment: OK, that sounds like a different question than originally proposed.  Would you like to go back and phrase it differently?